# Inequality for negative logarithms?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

Given $0 < x < y < 1$, is it possible to prove the following result:

$\frac {ln\:x}{ln\:y} < 1$?

Thanks

Comment: You *really* should take a look at the graph.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Since both logs are negative, this would be equivalent to $\ln x > \ln y$, but $\ln$ is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Take the inequality
$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln y} < 1$$

And multiply by $\ln y$:
$$\ln{x} > \ln{y}$$
(since $y<1$, $\ln y < 0$)

Now you can apply $e^x$ (which is monotone increasing) to both sides, to get
$$x > y$$

which contradicts the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;y<1\implies \log y<0\;$ , we get that

$$\frac{\log x}{\log y}<1\implies \log x>\log y $$

Yet we know that

$$(\log x)'=\frac1x>0\implies \log x\;\;\text{is monotone increasing}$$

and thus the inequality is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.